# Cakephp to Google Chart

Tags: cakephp, google-visualization

In my controller I create the array to be charted

```
function chart() {  
    $results = $this->Visit->query(
        "SELECT date(visits.created) as visit_date, 
            Count(visits.id) AS count_visits
            FROM visits
            GROUP BY date(visits.created)"
    );

    foreach($results AS $result) {
        $row = array(
            $result[0]['visit_date'],
            $result[0]['count_visits']          
        );
        $chartData[] = json_encode($row);
    }

    pr($chartData);

}
```

pr($chartData) gives following array

```
Array
 (
    [0] => ["2012-07-11","5"]
    [1] => ["2012-07-13","1"]
    [2] => ["2012-07-14","1"]
)
```

in chart view i have

```
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    // Create the data table.

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable($chartData);

    var options = {
      title: 'Visits by Date',
      hAxis: {title: 'Date', titleTextStyle: {color: 'black'}}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

but this doesn't get me a chart .. no errors ... just no chart ..

if I manually type in an array to test my view, it works fine ... eg if i replace ..

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable($chartData);
```

with  the following format from Google Chart example it generates a nice column chart

```
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['Date',  'Count'],  
      ['2012-07-11',  5],
      ['2012-07-13',  1],
      ['2012-07-14',  1]
    ]);
```

couple of questions:
- how do i get the header titles in the var data array?
- do double quotes or single quotes in array make a difference?
- am i passing the array $chartData from php to Google chart javascript correctly?
- the Google example has '[]' around the array, how do i get those around my array too?

(bwt, i know all about cakephp's Find(all) but I just got lost in documentation about how to get what i wanted and sql was much easier )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using json_encode in your controller, but in your view you are using -

```
google.visualization.arrayToDataTable($chartData);
```

json_encode creates json object, not and javascript array.

using json_encode in your controller function chart() try:

```
$chartData['cols'] = array(
    array('id' => 'visit_date', 'label' => 'Visit date', 'type' => 'date'),
    array('id' => 'count_visits', 'label' => 'Count', 'type' => 'number')
);
foreach($results AS $result) {
    $time = strtotime($result[0]['visit_date']);
    $dateJs = 'Date('.date("Y", $time).', '.(date('n', $time) - 1).', '.date('j', $time).')';
    $row = array(
        'c' => array(
            array('v' => $dateJs),
            array('v' => $result[0]['count_visits']),
         )
    );
    $chartData['rows'][] = $row;
}
//make the data available for view
$this->set('chartData', json_encode($chartData);
```

in your view use :

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable($chartData);
```